# Is there a crash or error message when running the robotframework-ride?

Tags: robotframework-ide

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbgCD.png)
When running ride. py on the computer terminal, the error shown in the picture appears, and there is a flashing error when running the program shortcut.

Looking forward to your answer, thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention basic info about versions and system. I can see it is Python3.10 in Windows, but can't tell the versions of RIDE and wxPython.

You also don't mention if RIDE was working OK before.

You can try to reset RIDE settings by following [this answer in RIDE FAQ page](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/wiki/F.A.Q.#16--q-i-have-closed-the-test-suites-tree-panel-and-now-i-cannot-restore-it-even-after-restarting-ride-current-version-20b2). The solution is to completely delete RIDE settings file, or to edit and remove the settings for the Panels positions (as I can tell from your error output).

Comment: Prior to this, Ride was able to start and run normally. When I closed the software and restarted Ride, I encountered the problem shown in the diagram. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Python, robotframework, and robotframework Ride, but the problem still persisted. My system is Windows 11, and the installed software versions are Robotframework-ride-2.0.8.1, wxPython-4.2.1, Robotframework-7.0, Python 3.9.13. I have also searched for relevant answers online, but still haven't found a suitable solution,Could  you do me a favor，Thank you very much！

Comment: When closing the UI interface of Ride, a prompt box popped up, but I didn't pay attention to the content of the prompt message and clicked "No" directly. Later, when I tried to restart, an error occurred

Comment: @user23336411 You should try do completely delete the settings directory, before running RIDE. You can do a backup of file settings.cfg, to later recover some settings, like Run arguments. Delete %APPDATA%\\Robotframework. After this, start RIDE, and see if this solved. If it did not, then try to install the current development version, 2.1dev21.

Comment: I deleted% APPDATA% \ \ Robotframework, and the software can start normally. Thank you very much